# Render JSON to table, if id matches

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I've got a table with 5 rows and two columns. Each row, has an ID column, ranging from 1-5.

I want to add JSON data to that said table, IF, that data has a matching ID to that row. If NO data matches that rows ID, add "No Matching Record" to that rows second column.

[image: Rendered Table]

**HTML Table**

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Json Data**

```
{"data":[
    {"id":"1", "lastName":"Doe"},
    {"id":"3", "lastName":"Jones"}
]}
```

**Expected Result**

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>No Matching Record</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Jones</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>No Matching Record</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>No Matching Record</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful (click again to undo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `.each()` to loop each `tr` and then use `find()` to get object from data that has same **id** as text in `td`.

```js
//Loop each row or tr
$('tbody tr').each(function() {
  //Get text or number from each first td in every row
  var i = $(this).find('td:first').text();
  //Find object from data with this id or current id of td
  var r = data.data.find((e) => e.id == i);
  //Select second td from current row
  var t = $(this).find('td:eq(1)');
  //If Object is found with current id add lastName as text else add dummy text or No Matching Record
  (r != undefined) ? t.text(r.lastName): t.text('No Matching Record');
});
```

```js
var data = {"data":[{"id":"1", "lastName":"Doe"},{"id":"3", "lastName":"Jones"}]}

$('tbody tr').each(function() {
  var i = $(this).find('td:first').text();
  var r = data.data.find((e) => e.id == i);
  var t = $(this).find('td:eq(1)');

  (r != undefined) ? t.text(r.lastName): t.text('No Matching Record');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Lastname</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

If you want to filter by index of rows instead of text from `td` you can just use `$(this).index() + 1;` and the rest is same

```js
var data = {
  "data": [{
    "id": "1",
    "lastName": "Doe"
  }, {
    "id": "3",
    "lastName": "Jones"
  }, ]
}

//Loop each row or tr
$('tbody tr').each(function() {
  //Get index of row
  var i = $(this).index() + 1;
  //Find object from data with this id or current id of td
  var r = data.data.find((e) => e.id == i);
  //Select second td from current row
  var t = $(this).find('td:eq(1)');
  //If Object is found with current id add lastName as text else add dummy text or No Matching Record
  (r != undefined) ? t.text(r.lastName): t.text('No Matching Record');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Lastname</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, add classes to the two types of `td`'s for convenience. Then following code should work. Here I am iterating through all rows in `tbody` and then searching through the json if any matching value is found. If no matching value is found, default value ("No data found") is put in the lastName column.

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="id">1</td>
        <td class="name"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="id">2</td>
        <td class="name"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="id">3</td>
        <td class="name"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="id">4</td>
        <td class="name"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="id">5</td>
        <td class="name"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>


var json = {"data":[
    {"id":"1", "lastName":"Doe"},
    {"id":"3", "lastName":"Jones"}
]};

$(".table tbody tr").each(function(index){
  var curId = $(this).find(".id").text();
  var nameField = "No data found";

  for( var i = 0; i < json.data.length; i++ )
  {
    var row = json.data[i];
    if( row.id == curId )
    {
      nameField = row.lastName;
      return false;
    }
  }

  $(this).find(".name").text( nameField );
});//each
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code would do the trick:

```
var response = {"data":[
    {"id":"1", "lastName":"Doe"},
    {"id":"3", "lastName":"Jones"}
]};

var myData = response.data;

var rows = $('#myDataTable tbody tr');
var cells, index, itemFound = false;

rows.each(function (index) {
   cells = $(this).find('td');
   itemFound = false
   for (index=myData.length-1 ; index>= 0 && !itemFound; index--) {
     if (cells.eq(0).text() == myData[index].id) {
       itemFound = true;
       cells.eq(1).text(myData[index].lastName);
       myData.splice(index, 1);
     }
   }
   if (!itemFound) {
     cells.eq(1).text('No matching record');
   }
});
```

See my working js fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/gkptnnxe/

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to add class or id's to your td's then you can use this.

```js
var obj = {"data":[
    {"id":"1", "lastName":"Doe"},
    {"id":"3", "lastName":"Jones"}
]};
var trs = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
// don't need for i==0
for(var i=1; i<trs.length; i++){
  var tds = trs[i].children;
  var id = tds[0].innerHTML;
  var nameFound = false;
  //search this id in json.
  var len = obj.data.length;
  for(var j=0; j<obj.data.length; j++){
    if(obj.data[j].id == id){
      // If found then change the value of this lastName cell.
      tds[1].innerHTML = obj.data[j].lastName;
      nameFound = true;
     }
  }
  // If id is not found is json then set the default message.
   if(nameFound == false){
     tds[1].innerHTML = "No mathcing records";
   }
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get `td` by `index` and check the `text` of td if it matches add name to next `td`

```
var data = {
            "data": [
             { "id": "1", "lastName": "Doe" },
             { "id": "3", "lastName": "Jones" }
            ]
        };

            $(".table-striped tbody tr").each(function(){
                var index = data.data.map(function (e) { return e.id }).indexOf($(this).first().text().trim());
                if(index > -1)
                    $(this).children('td:eq(1)').text(data.data[index].lastName);
                else
                    $(this).children('td:eq(1)').text('No matching record');

            });
```